# Ios pdf zooming at specific coordinate

Tags: ios, pdf, zooming

i created a Ios app for reading pdf documents following Apple pdf zooming  
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/zoomingpdfviewer/Introduction/Intro.html

but , i don't know how to zoom pdf pages at specific coordinate automatically ,

i mean when my did load method the pdf page zoomed at specific coordinate(x, y) such as : (10, 20)

some body help me ? please !

thank !

Answer (score 1):

[From Apple's Sample Code of Zooming PDF Viewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/zoomingpdfviewer/Introduction/Intro.html)

UIScrollView has the API to do that

```
 [yourScrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, Height) animated:YES];
```

**Basically if you want to see the animation on your changes then you can put your code in View did Appear method.**

```
#import "ZoomingPDFViewerViewController.h"
#import "PDFScrollView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ZoomingPDFViewerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /*
     Open the PDF document, extract the first page, and pass the page to the PDF scroll view.
     */
    NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestPage" withExtension:@"pdf"];

    CGPDFDocumentRef PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);

    CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
    [(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage];

    CGPDFDocumentRelease(PDFDocument);                
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // 1. Get the Scroll View
    UIScrollView *scrollView =  (UIScrollView*)self.view;

    // 2. Zoom to specified rect
    [scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, Height) animated:YES];


}
```